# Rename [google-maps-styled] to [google-maps-styling]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [google-maps-styled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-styled) tag has no usage/wiki but it is about the [styling options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/cloud-customization/overview) that are available when displaying a map with the various Google Maps APIs / SDKs.

I would therefore suggest to rename this tag to [google-maps-styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-styling) as this is the way Google identifies this functionnality.

I'll be happy to create a tag usage and wiki.

Comment: Tag [usage guidance and wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-styling/info) has been created.

Comment: Thanks! [The excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75307714/revisions) read way too much like marketing-speak to me, and, worse, missed the most important thing, which is to explain how the tag should be used (in this case, as in most cases, note that it should only be used for programming questions). I made some revisions to that. It is what most people struggle to write, compared with the long-form wiki.

Comment: @CodyGray OK... I am fine with your excerpt, but is it really necessary to include in every tag excerpt that it should be used only for programming questions? AFAIK, SO is all about programming questions...

Comment: I wish it weren't, but experience says that it is... Especially for things that are not *primarily* programming, like use of Google services, the mere existence of the tag is often enough to convince people that any/every question about that service is on-topic here. Therefore, we should take every step available to us and make every effort that we can to mitigate that perception.

Comment: All right. Got your point. Thanks.